# Evaluating dynamic EL expressions at runtime in JSP page

Tags: java, spring, jsp, el

I am putting together an application and would like to apply "Custom" EL Expressions to sections on the page when it is rendered.  This will help me control what parts are displayed on the page given the status of the page.  The problem is that the EL Expressions are not being evaluated and treated only as String values.  For example

```
<c:if test="${form.conditionEL}" >
  <input type="submit" value="Close">
</c:if>
```

The value of the ${field.conditionEL} might evaluate to something like "submission.status eq 'COMPLETE'".

So, is there a way to get that string value to be interpreted within the JSP page ?

Thanks for any help in making this happen.  Let me know if I missed providing any pertinent information to help resolve.

Environment:  Java 8, Tomcat 9, JSP 3.0, Spring

Regards,

Mike

Comment: http://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 0):

I would simply add the submission status to the page context which let's you simply do:

```
<c:if test="${submissionStatus eq 'COMPLETE'}" >
  <input type="submit" value="Close">
</c:if>
```

Comment: Yes.  That would be the easy way, but not the dynamic way I looking to do.  The dynamic would allow the Admin to design the form to not show a field based on a specific data point.  When I have tried to evaluate the dynamic condition as ${form.conditionEL} for my above scenario it is shown as "submission.status eq 'COMPLETE'".  When I put that exact conditional statement below my dynamic one it will evaluate as "true".  So, would love to know of a way to make sure that the string I am writing out can get evaluated.

Comment: Then create a boolean in you backend and add that to the page context.

Comment: Hmmm.. Evaluate the conditions on the backend and store that result.  That might just work nicely. Have you ever used <spring:eval> tag ?

Answer (score -1):

Check whether EL expressions are ignored in your page tag. I've also faced the same issue and this resolved mine.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" isELIgnored="false" %>
```

Comment: They are all working except for the Dynamic ones.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Why do you need such a functionality?. EL and JSTL are best used in a MVC environment.In an MVC environment, all the HTTP flow issues are handled in a servlet and the real business functionality (model) is handled in beans. Only when all the processing is done does the context get passed to a JSP (view) for display.

Comment: It allows the Administrative user to have more control of when content can display.  If I wanted to allow the Admin to decide when a button would display by defining the condition.  This would increase the flexibility of the system.

Comment: The same can be achieved by passing submissionStatus as the model attribute and checking for (${submissionStatus eq 'COMPLETE'}). Why are you passing this inside another attribute? If you still wanna proceed without approach, scriptlets is what you are looking for. You can basically write java code to handle all your cases

Comment: The example of submissionStatus is just one example of options that might be available to the end user to control what displays.  The use of scriptlets is another option as well as the recommendation by Jasper above to evaluate the condition on the backend before it is passed to the View.  I think the <spring:eval> tag might work as well after some intial testing.  Thank you for the feedback.